# На общей странице выборов нет StackOverflow на русском

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, выборы, stackexchange

Есть [общая страница выборов для Stack Exchange](http://elections.stackexchange.com/). У нас выборы начались, но сайта там нет.

Raspberry Pi и Software Recommendations присутствовали там еще на этапе выдвижения кандидатов (как у нас сейчас).

http://elections.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Tim Stone](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/26183620#26183620) починил страницу. Спасибо за замечание.

К сожалению, статистика по знакам на общей странице не соответствует реальности, поскольку не сходятся их (переведённые) названия. Но количество знаком отражено в сводке "баллы кандидата" непосредственно на  [странице выборов сайта](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/election).